# Semaphore is not waiting swift

Tags: swift, semaphore

I'm trying to do 3 async requests and control the load with semaphores to know when all have loaded.

I Init the semaphore in this way:

```
let sem = dispatch_semaphore_create(2);
```

Then send to background the waiting for semaphore code:

```
let backgroundQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_BACKGROUND, 0)
dispatch_async(backgroundQueue) { [unowned self] () -> Void in
    println("Waiting for filters load")
    dispatch_semaphore_wait(sem, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
    println("Loaded")
}
```

Then I signal it 3 times (on each request `onSuccess` and `onFailure`):

```
dispatch_semaphore_signal(sem)
```

But when the signal code arrives it already passed the semaphore wait code, it never waits to subtract the semaphore count.

why?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You've specified `dispatch_semaphore_create` with a parameter of `2` (which is like calling `dispatch_semaphore_signal` twice), and then signal it three more times (for a total of five), but you appear to have only one wait (which won't wait at all because you started your semaphore with a count of `2`).

That's obviously not going to work. Even if you fixed that (e.g. use zero for the creation of the semaphore and then issue three waits) this whole approach is inadvisable because you're unnecessarily tying up a thread waiting for the the other requests to finish.

This is a textbook candidate for dispatch groups. So you would generally use the following:

1. Create a `dispatch_group_t`:

   ```
   dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();
   ```
2. Then do three `dispatch_group_enter`, once before each request.
3. In each of the three `onSuccess`/`onFailure` blocks pairs, do a `dispatch_group_leave` in both block.
4. Create a `dispatch_group_notify` block that will be performed when all of the requests are done.